# Temporary speed improvements

Tags: arangodb

In our workflow, we have little ongoing work in the arangodb (~1% cpu use).  For about 30 minutes of the day usage spikes and we need it to be more performant (helping do a 3s query to 1s).

Instead of moving up the instance box that it's hosted on, is there a way to get more out of arango temporarily during peak times?  Would this be clustering or should we just look into temporarily boosting the instance that it's on.

Comment: It's hard to tell how to speed up the instance when usage spikes, as this will pretty much depend on the actual workload. Can you elaborate a bit what usually happens during the 30 min usage peak, e.g. will there be lots of read-only queries, many inserts/updates etc.? Additionally, have you checked whether any of the individual operations executed during the load spike (AQL queries, transactions) can be sped up? Getting a bit more details would help.

Comment: hi @stj basically we collect data throughout the day and for 30 minutes it's analyzed by crons or a user in a dashboard.  I'm trying to come up with a way on how to speed up the dashboard portion during which we can pause any new writes

Comment: If writes are paused, one potential way of speed up queries is to turn on the AQL query result cache for the period when there is only read-access to the data. That will help if queries repeat (a lot). Apart from that, what will help most if to have the right indexes in place so that they support the search conditions for the most expensive queries.

Answer (score 1):

Accumulating above suggestions plus adding some more that fit the generic nature of this question.

- if possible split read/write workload, either in a timely fashion by holding back writes, or by switching to a new collection for the new writes.
- make sure indices are properly set (use [explain](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/execution-and-performance-explaining-queries.html))
- try whether [query profiling](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/execution-and-performance-query-profiler.html) can help you improve the performance